# zipwithindex for Rdd Key and get new RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am creating rdd with `wholeTextfiles`. I am getting filepath and filetext. I want new `RDD` with filepath and index from `zipWithIndex`

I have tried map but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *First thing is  this needed at all ?  theorically we can do... but what is the necessity of doing this as requirement. you can write
>   plain hdfs program to find the file name and index.. I mean spark rdd
>   is no more needed to display file names. with index.*

---

I have below files.

[image: sample parquet files here]

Now I am doing tranformation like below...

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

/** *
  * @author : Ram Ghadiyaram
  */
object WholeTextFiles extends Logging {
  Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val appName = if (args.length > 0) args(0) else this.getClass.getName
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .config("spark.master", "local[*]") //.config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()

// map transformation to form new rdd
    val finalresult = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\codebase\\spark-general-examples\\userdata*.parquet")
    .zipWithIndex().map {
      case (x, index) => (index, x._1)
    }

    println("  print the small rdd this is your tranformed RDD ")

     finalresult.sortByKey(true) foreach {
      case (index,x ) => println(s"\n Index $index file name  ${x}  ")
    }
    println("done")
  }
}
```

Result :

```
  print the small rdd this is your tranformed RDD 

 Index 0 file name  file:/C:/Users/Downloads/codebase/spark-general-examples/userdata1.parquet  

 Index 3 file name  file:/C:/Users/Downloads/codebase/spark-general-examples/userdata4.parquet  

 Index 1 file name  file:/C:/Users/Downloads/codebase/spark-general-examples/userdata2.parquet  

 Index 4 file name  file:/C:/Users/Downloads/codebase/spark-general-examples/userdata5.parquet  

 Index 2 file name  file:/C:/Users/Downloads/codebase/spark-general-examples/userdata3.parquet  
done
```

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you